# Jwt authentication React/AspNetCore Web Api 2.1

Tags: reactjs, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing full stack web application and so far I've done the following things:

- Created Login and Registration form components in React
- Developed an api with users and some basic data that users can use
- In my api (in account controller) I've created login and register methods that are in charge for adding identity users to db and creating json web tokens for each of them.

Now I'm stucked because I'm not sure what and how should I use those tokens in my frontend. I saw some examples , ie. on this link : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/06/react-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example#home-page-jsx  but it's really confusing to me ( since I'm begginer to  react). Does anyone have any idea, example or specific direction how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that once a user logs in, you should send the client the token you generated on your server.

Then, the client should save that token as a cookie or to localstorage (not recommended for security reasons).

After that, the client should send the token together with each request it makes to the server.

On your server, you should decrypt the token received from the client and authenticate the user. If the user should have access to the specific resource he is trying to access, you should return a response with the data. If the token is invalid, you should return a response with an error status stating that the user is unauthenticated.

Check out [this article on medium](https://medium.com/@SilentHackz/simple-way-to-secure-react-apps-using-jwt-and-react-router-2b4a05d780a3) for more details regarding implementation.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you want to use this token. But as an answer to your question, let's assume, you want protect a route. In other words, only visitors with a valid token can visit a certain page which we will call as "../anyroute".

Down below, you may find a simple react component for rendering ".../anyroute". When a visitor wants to go to this page, our useState hook will force browser to send a request to the server to get a status code. If server says "ok"(`200`), then our protected content ("Treasure is in Greece") will render, if server responds as "not ok", then our warning content will render ("You need to login my good sir").

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const Anycomponent = () => {

  const [requireAuth, setRequireAuth] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/anyroute")
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setRequireAuth(true)
      } else {
        setRequireAuth(false)
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return(
    <div className="createArticle">
      {requireAuth && <div> Treasure is in Greece </div>}
      {!requireAuth && <div>You need to login my good sir</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Anycomponent;
```

After that, you can populate server.js file accordingly. Here we downloaded a small package called "cookie-parser". It verifies our browser token by using the keyword (`asdf12345`) that we used when we created jwt in signup or login process. If verified it sends a `200` code, if not `401` code (Unauthorized)

```
...
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(cookieParser());
...
app.get("/anyroute", function(req, res){
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, "asdf12345", () => {
      res.status(200).end();
    })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    res.send("Tokens didnt match");
  }
});
```